# How to prevent negative count/ negative numbers

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a app where there is a text view which shows coins 00 and a button show reward video ads to give 10 coins to the user & a buy button to decrease the coins by 30. Now when the user have 30 coins, on clicking the buy button it sets the text coins to 00 but when he has less than 30 coins it sets the text to negative ( say i have 20 coins and when i click buy it sets the text to -10 ).

**what I want**

I want to show a toast when the user clicks buy button when his coins are 0 and I dont want the value to go negative.

**My code**

```
 mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.money);
    coinCount = 0;
    mText.setText(" " + coinCount);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buynow);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (coinCount <= 0) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You dont have enough coins", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                    coinCount = coinCount - 30;
                    mText.setText(String.valueOf(coinCount));
                }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change condition from:

```
if (coinCount <= 0)
```

to

```
if (coinCount < 30)
```

because you shouldn't subtract any value of `coinCount`, when it's less than 30. You just inform user that there is not enough coins.

---

*I would also like to suggest you to store amount of coins to subtract in a variable. That way, when one day you decide to change amount of coins to subtract, you can do it in only one place, not it the whole code that uses this value. For example:*

```
mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.money);
int costOfTransactionInCoins = 30; // new variable
coinCount = 0;
...
if (coinCount < costOfTransactionInCoins) {
   ... }
else {
    coinCount = coinCount - costOfTransactionInCoins;
...
}
...
```

Comment: @JoyDey Glad that I could help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
if (coinCount <= 0)
```

to this:

```
if (coinCount <= 29)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. so this means I will have to set the value -1 of the value to be deducted in order to prevent negative numbers,

Comment: Nope, it's <= 29 which is equivalent to < 30. If a user has exactly 30 coins they should still be able to buy things. No negative numbers unless you subtract more than 30.